# GETH configuration - what is the difference between '--testnet' and '--network 3'?

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I'm reading [GETH Command-Line Options Guide](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), which says:

```
--testnet            Ropsten network: pre-configured proof-of-work test network
--networkid value    Network identifier (integer, 1=Frontier, 2=Morden (disused), 3=Ropsten, ...)
```

What exactly is the difference between `--testnet` and `--network 3`?

Do I have to use both, or can I use either one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each network has an ID and a name.

The network ID of Ropsten is 3.

The network ID of the Main Network is 1.

`--network 3` evaluates to Ropsten, which also happens to be the default test network in the GETH client.

Comment: Do I have to use both, or can I use either one?

Comment: You can use either one.